# No "Base" checkbox in Localizable.strings

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

After creating Localizable.strings I cannot add Base localization because of missing checkbox. I can add any other language, but Base is simply missing. How to get Base checkbox available there?

Localizable.srings screenshot:

[image: Localizable.srings]

What I need to get (Main.storyboard screenshot):

[image]